# Чи слова "другий" та "друзі" походять від спільного кореня?

Tags: етимологія, прикметники, числівники

В інтернеті є [дані](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3) про те що слово [*друг*](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzi) (у множині [*друзі*](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzi)) походить від [**drugъ*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/drug%D1%8A):

> From Proto-Slavic *drugъ, from Proto-Indo-European *dʰrowgʰos. Cognate with Lithuanian draũgas ‎(“friend”), Gothic  ‎(gadrauhts, “warrior”) and Old English *drihten*.

Наразі мені не вдається з'ясувати походження <s>прикметника</s> числівника [*другий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/drughyj). Я помітив що `г` у прикметнику не змінюється при змінах слова.

**Від якого кореня походить <s>прикметник</s> числівник *другий*?**

Answer (score 3):

Кажуть, що обидва слова - когнати, тобто, [пішли від одного кореня](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%B9%D0%B3%D1%8A#.D0.A1.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D1.8F.D0.BD.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9)

> другой, всякий человек, ближний
>
> товарищ, сообщник, спутник

Дивимось на [походження *прикметника* "другой"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9), бо вочевидь прикметник (*други́й* у значенні "інший") та числівник (*дру́гий*) пішли від одного кореня:

> Происходит от форм, родств. ст.-слав. дрѹгъ (др.-греч. ἄλλος; Супр.), ср.: ст.-слав. дроугъ дроуга ἀλλήλους, укр. *дру́гий* «*второй*», белор. другí — то же, болг. дру́ги, сербохорв. дру̏гӣ, словенск. drȗg «другой», drúgi «второй», чешск. druhý «второй», druh druha «друг друга», польск. drugi «второй», в.-луж. druhi

Answer (score 1):

Також в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1985/EtSlUkrM_1985.pdf) (ст. 133-134) ми можемо знайти підтвердження того, що ці два слова походять від старослов'янського "**дрѹгъ**".